# Translations string email not work

Tags: 8, i18n-l10n, emails

in D8 (multilanguage site, with two languages) i wanna send email for registration, etc by user preference of language of user (People -> Edit people -> Language Settings)

I've enabled all modules for translations and translations are saved correctly (see the attachment).[image]

I followed this guide: https://www.valuebound.com/resources/blog/how-to-send-mail-programmatically-drupal-8 
but not work for me.

The language code passed for the email is correct but the email is always send in default language (in my case, english).

Answer (score 0):

Be sure that the string you sent by mail is already translated in the target language. Otherwise it will not work. You can check it here http://youwebsite.com/admin/config/regional/translate

Comment: Hi Stephane, translation for email is at this url http://yourwebsite.com/language-default-code/admin/config/people/accounts/translate/language-code-for-translations/edit (in my case, language-default-code = en and language-code-for-translations = it)

Answer (score 0):

For solve this problem, in hook_mail insert this:

```
    $token = \Drupal::service('token');
    $language_manager = \Drupal::languageManager();
    $language = $language_manager->getLanguage($user->getPreferredLangcode());
    $original_language = $language_manager->getConfigOverrideLanguage();
    $language_manager->setConfigOverrideLanguage($language);
    $mail_config = \Drupal::config('user.mail');

    $subject = $token->replace($mail_config->get($key . '.subject'), [
        'user' => $user
    ]);

    $body = $token->replace($mail_config->get($key . '.body'), [
        'user' => $user
    ]);

    $language_manager->setConfigOverrideLanguage($original_language);
```